# Nginx service would not stop, what should I do?

Tags: centos, nginx

I am on a newly bought server with CentOS 8 and the latest Nginx.

I try to stop Nginx:

```
[root@mymachine run]# nginx -s stop
nginx: [error] invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
```

Not working.

The web is still live. I can use `curl -I http://mysite.com` to view the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.1
```

And I found a lot of process:

```
[root@mymachine run]# ps -aux | grep "nginx"
root       22584  0.0  0.1 156164 11292 ?        S    Sep17   0:03 nginx: worker process
root       22585  0.0  0.1 155836 10832 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22586  0.0  0.1 155836  9348 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22587  0.0  0.1 155836  9348 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22588  0.0  0.1 155836  9348 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22589  0.0  0.1 155836  9348 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22590  0.0  0.1 155836  9348 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22591  0.0  0.1 155836  9348 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       22592  0.0  0.1 155836  9144 ?        S    Sep17   0:00 nginx: cache manager process
root       26125  0.0  0.0  12108  1080 pts/0    S+   09:11   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

What should I do to totally turn off nginx?

Why did this happen?

Update for **systemctl status nginx.service** results:

```
[root@mymachine ~]# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-09-18 09:34:52 CST; 20min ago
  Process: 1868 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1865 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1862 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 18 09:34:51 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:51 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:51 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:51 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:52 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:52 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:52 mymachine nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 18 09:34:52 mymachine systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 18 09:34:52 mymachine systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 18 09:34:52 mymachine systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume it’s using the systemd service?  Did you try `systemctl status nginx.service`?

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question.

Comment: It looks like you tried to start nginx outside of systemd and so it can’t shut it down.